# Validating Checkbox and Radio Button in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using c# for coding!

Below is my html for checkbox and radion button

```
  <input type="radio" style="float: left;" name="documents" id="Checkbox9" value="yes"
                        runat="server" />
                    <label style="width: 35px!important;" class="checkbox">
                        <%=GetResourceString("c_HSGStudent")%>
                    </label>
                    <input type="radio" style="float: left;" name="documents" id="Checkbox10" value="no"
                        runat="server" />
                    <label style="width: 25px!important;" class="checkbox">
                        <%=GetResourceString("c_HSGParent")%>
                    </label>
                    <input type="radio" style="float: left;" cheked name="documents" id="Radio1" value="yes"
                        runat="server" />
                    <label style="width: 35px!important;" class="checkbox">
                        <%=GetResourceString("c_HSGStudent")%>
                    </label>
                    <input type="radio" style="float: left;" name="documents" id="Radio2" value="no"
                        runat="server" />
                    <label style="width: 25px!important;" class="checkbox">
                        <%=GetResourceString("c_HSGParent")%>
                    </label>
```

You can see I have two checkboxes and two radio buttons, My problem is that on my submit button click I want to check whether user have checked at-least one checkbox or radio button. It will be good if we can have .NET solution like (customvalidator).

Please suggest!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add a CustomValidator to your page...

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CheckBoxRequired" EnableClientScript="true" 
    OnServerValidate="CheckBoxRequired_ServerValidate" 
    OnClientValidate="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

You can then then validate them from a client side function with a simple jquery call...

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate(sender, e) 
{ 
    e.IsValid = $("input[name='documents']").is(':checked'); 
} 

</script>
```

code-behind for server side validation...

```
protected void CheckBoxRequired_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e) 
{ 
    e.IsValid = Checkbox9.Checked || Checkbox10.Checked || Radio1.Checked || Radio2.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validator and then check wether the controls meet the criteria in the servervalidate event handler.